# Altering cassandra table by adding new column while inserting data

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise, datastax

I have high frequency of data for insertion in cassandra table.And column are dynamic .As per my scenario i want to alter my static table and add new column while insertion process.
Does it impact on insertion or create any lock Or performance issue?

Note :I dont want to use dynamic column family.
Please suggest ..

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should not impact your performance very dramatically. Cassandra is good for such types of operations. (E.g. in relational databases like MySQL it might be quite heavy operation). In case you use Cassandra 2.0, you can use batch to execute both operations: 1. alter table and 2. update column. In this case you will have only one network round-trip.

Comment: Will it block write operations during new column addition? Will the client get error when this column addition process is undergoing?